# Перенос строки в регулярном выражении

Tags: java, регулярные-выражения

Здравствуй сообщество, вопрос прост почему данная функция отрабатывает не так как нужно. Вроде бы должно всё игнорировать так как я добавил \s. Что само странно работает через одну строку то есть частично верно. Помогите кто что знает лучше чем я, так как в регулярных выражениях дилетант.

```
public static String convert1(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll(";[\\w\\s]*;", " ==> ");
}
input = "Login;Name;Email
ivanov;Ivan Ivanov;ivanov@mail.ru
петров;Петр Петров;petrov@google.com
obama;Barack Obama;obama@google.com
bush;Джордж Буш;bush@mail.ru"
```

Вот вывод после обработки:

[image: Вывод после выполнения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вы забыли "включить" поддержку всего Юникода для `\w` и `\s` с помощью `(?U)` (опция `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`):

```
return input.replaceAll("(?U);[\\w\\s]*;", " ==> ");
                         ^^^^
```

См. [демо онлайн](https://ideone.com/HfIIis):

```
public static String convert1(String input) {
    return input.replaceAll("(?U);[\\w\\s]*;", " ==> ");
}

public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
{
    String input = "Login;Name;Email\n"+
    "ivanov;Ivan Ivanov;ivanov@mail.ru\n"+
    "петров;Петр Петров;petrov@google.com\n"+
    "obama;Barack Obama;obama@google.com\n"+
    "bush;Джордж Буш;bush@mail.ru";
    System.out.println(convert1(input));
}
```

Результат:

```
Login ==> Email
ivanov ==> ivanov@mail.ru
петров ==> petrov@google.com
obama ==> obama@google.com
bush ==> bush@mail.ru
```

Comment: Да, вы правы спасибо, а можно объяснить почему это повлияло? тут вроде нет кириллицы или символов 2х байтовой кодировки

Comment: @OlexiePolishchyk Как нет кириллицы? В тексте её полно. `\w` только при наличии `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` правильно находит все цифры, буквы и ещё кое-какие символы.

Comment: ах, да Петров портит всю малину, завтыкал спасибо ещё раз за помощь